# Comparison between sqrt(x) and x**(1./2.)

Tags: fortran

I just had a quick question which resulted from an observation I made when trying to get the square root of a number in Fortran. Comparing the following two statements

```
    wp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
    somevar = sqrt(3.0)
    somevar2 = (3.0_wp)**(1.0/2.0)
```

I find that somevar =1.7320507764816284 and somevar2 = 1.7320508075688772. According to https://apod.nasa.gov/htmltest/gifcity/sqrt3.1mil it seems that somevar2 is the more correct answer. My question is if the statement

```
    squareroot = real(x,wp) ** (1.0/2.0)
```

will always result in a more correct value for the square root of a number?

If so does this relate to the fact that the `sqrt()` function returns a single precision variable by default or is this a matter relating to the compiler being used?

Comment: A nitpicker would also like to see `_wp` in the fraction `(1.0/2.0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sqrt` you reference here is a *generic intrinsic* function.  This generic accepts any real or complex argument and returns a result of the same type and kind as the argument.

In this case, the argument `3.0` is a real (literal constant) of default kind, so the result is also a real of default kind.  On the other hand, the expression `(3.0_wp)**(1.0/2.0)` is a real with kind parameter `wp`.  It's quite likely that this is a real with higher precision than the other real.

If you write `sqrt(3.0_wp)` then the two expressions will be of the same kind, and I'd expect the two values to agree more closely.

More generally, I wouldn't expect the second expression to always give a more accurate result.

Comment: sqrt(3_wp) should be implemented with an IEEE accurate instruction on most targets, or it may  be calculated at compile time with a high precision library, depending on your compiler.

Comment: @tim18 What do you mean by accurate? Both of those expressions can be done at compile time, but the same rules as in runtime should be followed.

Answer (score 3):

Let us dissect the code here a bit. This is all consistent with the comments and answers already given but I feel like there is still a bit of mistery that can be solved.

```
somevar = sqrt(3.0)
```

Here, `3.0` is a constant that will be stored as the default precision (probably a 32 bit floating point value. that is default with gfortran anyway). So `sqrt` will compute the square root to that accuracy.

For `somevar2`, the base number is defined to precision `wp` but the exponent not.

```
somevar2 = (3.0_wp)**(1.0/2.0)
```

This has no impact as `1.0/2.0` is stored exactly in the binary representation. You can check this by comparing the two accuracies as:

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: wp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
  real :: default_prec_half
  real(kind=wp) :: wp_prec_half

  default_prec_half = 1.0/2.0
  wp_prec_half = 1.0_wp/2.0_wp

  write(*,*) default_prec_half, wp_prec_half, default_prec_half-wp_prec_half

end program test
```

The output for the difference is exactly 0.

For illustration, I use the typed routines of NumPy to check the assertions:

```
import numpy as np
sqrt_3_32 = np.sqrt(3, dtype=np.float32)
sqrt_3_64 = np.sqrt(3, dtype=np.float64)
print(sqrt_3_32, sqrt_3_64)
```

Using both results, I check the accuracy of `somevar` and `somevar2`:

```
In [67]: somevar = 1.7320507764816284

In [68]: somevar2 = 1.7320508075688772

In [69]: somevar-sqrt_3_64
Out[69]: -3.1087248775207854e-08

In [70]: somevar-sqrt_3_32
Out[70]: 0.0

In [72]: somevar2-sqrt_3_64
Out[72]: 0.0

In [73]: somevar2-sqrt_3_32
Out[73]: 3.1087248775207854e-08
```

What comes out of this is:

1. `somevar` is the square root of 3 up to the default accuracy and has the same value as the 32-bit NumPy computed square root of 3.
2. `somevar2` is the square root of 3 up to the `wp` accuracy that is the same as the 64-bit NumPy computer square root of 3.

**Note:** I could do the comparison because the accuracies match on my platform. Although this is *generally* the case, I provided the comparison for illustration and you should pick the accuracy that is appropriate for your problem and use it consistently in your program. See the [fortran90.org](http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#floating-point-numbers) paragraph on floating point numbers for a general guideline.